# Find $S_Y(f)$ with given $H(f)$ and $S_X(f)$

Tags: stochastic-processes

I am a bit confused about some calculations of an example from a textbook:

Given:
$$S_X(f)=N_0/2$$
$$S_Y(f)=|H(f)|^2 S_X(f) $$
with $$H(f) = e^{-j\pi fT}T\frac{sin(\pi Tf)}{\pi Tf}$$

From the textbook, the $S_Y(f)$ is:
$$S_Y(f)= T^2 [\frac{sin(\pi Tf)}{\pi Tf}]^2 \frac{N_0}{2} $$

**However, my result is:**
$$S_Y(f)= e^{-j2\pi fT}T^2 [\frac{sin(\pi Tf)}{\pi Tf}]^2 \frac{N_0}{2} $$
where does $e^{-j2\pi fT}$ go? Why did the text book emitted this term? I believe that there is a conversion but I am not sure about this.

Comment: You forgot the $|.|$ sign. For any real number $t$ we have $|e^{jt}|=1$.

Comment: This is exactly what I need to remember. Thank you so much!